# Safely passing a query string to an echoed URL in Cake 2.4

Tags: php, json, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.4

In CakePHP 2.4, how do I safely pass my view query string to a custom URL query string?

Essentially, when visiting the view at `posts/map?param1=1&param2=2`, I need the view to echo `/posts/points.json?param1=1&param2=2`.

**EDIT:** Hacky workaround for HtmlHelper munging `&` into `&amp`;

```
    echo str_replace("&amp;", "&", $this->Html->url(array(
        'controller' => 'posts',
        'action' => 'points',
        'ext' => 'json',
        '?' => $this->request->query
        )));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [passed-named-or-query-string-params](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/05/04/passed-named-or-query-string-params/).

You should use query strings in CakePHP2.x
Those are the correct form of passing values between urls via GET.
They also play nicely with extensions.

Also, your action name is wrong.
You should separate it into "action" and "ext":

```
array(
    'controller' => 'posts',
    'action' => 'points',
    'ext' => 'json',
    '?' => array('param1' => 1, ...)
),
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I've actually already read your blog post, and I'll consider switching to query strings, but I'm currently using the CakeDC Search plugin, which uses named params.

Comment: No, since I mainly wrote it I know for a fact that it quite well works with query strings - that is also mentioned in the linked post above by the way, how to get it working with query strings :) Note the `$config['Search']` part.

Comment: I meant the CakeDC search plugin. I would even say query strings works better than named params with it these days. Tip: Try the development branch - it has a little bit more functionality that did not yet end up in the master branch.

Comment: I'm so embarrassed to not have known about the query strings option! Thanks, you've pointed me in the right direction, I've already switched over. Maybe the Github docs code snippets could be revised to deprecate named params?

Comment: They really should. Maybe you can make a PR with that information some time.